# Create an array of temp files in python

Tags: python, for-loop, temporary-files

I am trying to create an array of temp files with NamedTempopraryFile, however it does not seem to work the way I intend. Only one temp file is create and the function returns, rather than however many elements are in db_file_paths.

Does anyone see anything wrong?

example input:    `db_file_path = ["/mnt/somedir/data_0" , /mnt/somedir/data_1"]`

```
def create_ini(db_file_paths):

    #array of file tmpfs ini filehandles
    file_handles = []

    for path in db_file_paths:
        #make a tempfs file handle
        f_handle = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
        #match and replace db dummy file path
        f_handle = replace( f_handle.name, source_ini, pattern, path )
        file_handles.append(f_handle)
        return file_handles
```

Comment: The best way should be to step through the code in `pdb`.

Comment: I see a possible wrong: `db_file_path` vs `db_file_paths`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You return at the end of the first iteration of the for-loop. re-indent the last line so that it will be executed only after the for-loop has ended.

```
def create_ini(db_file_paths):

    #array of file tmpfs ini filehandles
    file_handles = []

    for path in db_file_paths:
        #make a tempfs file handle
        f_handle = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
        #match and replace db dummy file path
        f_handle = replace( f_handle.name, source_ini, pattern, path )
        file_handles.append(f_handle)
    return file_handles # <-- change of indentation here
```